# The configured history level with id='123' is not registered in this config

Tags: java, spring-boot, camunda

I'm trying to deploy camunda under Tomcat 9 to acces to camunda cockpit interface.
For some technical reasons i have to set my history level to 123 using this java code (Spring-boot):

ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngineConfiguration
.createProcessEngineConfigurationFromResourceDefault()
.setHistory(123)
.buildProcessEngine();

In my bpm-platform.xml file under $TOM_CAT_HOME/conf, i set history level to 123:

```
<properties>
  <property name="history">123</property>
  <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate">true</property>
  <property name="authorizationEnabled">true</property>
  <property name="jobExecutorDeploymentAware">true</property>
  <property name="historyCleanupBatchWindowStartTime">00:01</property>
</properties>
```

it seams that this configuration is not taken by server.

> Caused by: org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: ENGINE-08043 Exception while performing 'deploy BPM platform' => 'Start process engine default': invalid history level: 123

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide a lib for tomcat that actually implements the historyLevel interface and claims the 123 id.